# A question about thinking modules as free Abelian groups

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

First of all, I am aware that my question is not so clear. I am trying to understand the structure of number fields and their ring of integers.

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is its ring of integers . Then, we can say these:

> $K$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, it has some finite basis consisting of elements of $K$. Actually, there is more. $K$can be considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space with basis elements belonging to $\mathcal{O}_K$.
>
> $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that it has a basis $\{\alpha_1, \dots,\alpha_n\}$ where each $\alpha_i$ belong to $\mathcal{O}_K$.

My problem is that I do not know when should I think $K$ or $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a free Abelian group like $\mathcal{O}_K = \alpha_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus\dots\oplus\alpha_n\mathbb{Z}$ or as a finitely generated module.

Can someone please explain all the connections between $K$ / $\mathcal{O}_K$ and modules/free Abelian groups?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a finitely generated abelian group. $K$ is not; instead it is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: So can I think O_K as both a vector space and a finitely generated abelian group?

Comment: No. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a finitely generated abelian group and not a vector space; $K$ is a vector space and not a finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: Why can not I think it as a vector space? Is it because that we can not talk about a field and there is no linear independence among $\alpha_i$'s?

Comment: You can talk about linear dependence and independence over something more general than a field. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a (free) $\mathbb{Z}$-module and you can talk about linear dependence and independence over $\mathbb{Z}$, but it simply is not a vector space over any field.

Comment: Thank you for all your help but I have one more question. Now I am confused because even though it can not be considered as a vector space then how can we talk about its rank?

I think that rank of a module is the dimension of it as a vector space. Should I think like the rank is the cardinality of the smallest set that can generate the whole structure?

Comment: You can talk about the rank of a module over a ring more general than a field. It is not the size of the smallest set of generators, except when the module is free.

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: If $D$ is an integral domain, the rank of a $D$-module $M$ is the dimension of the vector space $M \otimes_D K$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $D$. Here $D = \mathbb{Z}$ has field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong K$, so the rank of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the dimension of $K$ as a vector space.

Comment: You can think to $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{Z}$-vector space with basis $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $K$ as the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Just the word is "finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}$-module" because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so the properties are slightly different. Also $\mathcal{O}_K$ has a (commutative) multiplication : you can think to the $a_i$ as [some matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $\mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$.

Answer (score 1):

To "explain all the connections between $K / O_K$ and modules/free Abelian groups", one could simply say that $K\cong O_K \otimes \mathbf Q$, but immediately warn that doing so "kills" all the arithmetic of $O_K$. Since you must be aware of this, I guess that your question rather concerns the differences, in the context of linear algebra, between the structures of vector spaces and free modules (what can be done in a vector space which cannot be done in a free module).

Throughout, $V$ (resp. $M$) will denote implicitly a finitely generated vector space (resp. module) over a commutative field (resp. ring) $F$ (resp. $R$). The central notion in linear algebra is that of linear (in)dependence. This requires to get rid of the "torsion submodule" $tM$ of $M$, i.e. of the elements $m\in M$ such that $r.m =0$ for a certain non null $r\in R$ (just think of a finite abelian group). So the ring $R$ should be a $domain$ (no non null divisors of zero), but even if $R=\mathbf Z$, one should also avoid finite modules. In the usual definition, an $R$-module $M$ is free iff it admits a basis over $R$, i.e. $M\cong R^n$ as $R$-modules for a certain $n$, which is its (well defined) rank. An $F$-vector space is automatically free (why ?), but this is not true for a general $R$-module $M$, even if $R$ is a domain and $M$ has no torsion. The most well known smooth result is that, if the ring $R$ is principal, then $M$ is free iff $M$ has no torsion (apart from $0$ of course). This applies to $O_K$ over $\mathbf Z$ (the "absolute" case), but for a general finite extension $L/K$ of number fields (the "relative" case), it does *not* apply to $O_L$ over $O_K$. Besides, even in the absolute case, one cannot *a priori* complete a given linearly independent system of elements of $O_K$ to get a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $O_K$(same "why" as before). This is the difficult problem of finding an *integral basis*, which is not the same thing as a basis of $K$ consisting of integral elements.

As noticed above, another reason *not* to consider $O_K$ simply as a module lies in the arithmetic of $O_K$, which is a ring, not merely an additive group. For example, consider the multiplicative group $U_K$ of units (=invertible elements) of $O_K$. It is a $\mathbf Z$-module (in multiplicative notation), its torsion is the (finite) group $\mu_K$ of roots of unity of $K$, but the determination of the rank of the free $\mathbf Z$-module $U_K /\mu_K$ is not a trivial matter (Dirichlet's unit theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer, I am amazed. Can we say that every $F$-vector space is a free module since it has a basis so that we can talk about linearly independent set of elements?

Comment: You take the question by the wrong end. A F-vector space V is always free because it always admits a basis. The proof rests on the following equivalence : basis = maximal set of linearly independent vectors = minimal set of generators. If you write down the proof of this equivalence, you'll see that at a certain point, you *divide * by a non zero scalar. This does not work for a general module.